# Which HTTPClient can be used for long running process

Tags: apache, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a requirement where I would need to call a servlet end point.
The servlet does the huge task. It might take about hours to do task.

Keeping all these, I need to build a http client which keeps connection and call this end point. I am not interested in the response. It should just call the endpoint and forget. Which client should i use ?

I tried with apache http client

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
httpclient.start();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);`
Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request,null);
```

Does this call the end point of the servlet, because I don't see any logs of the servlet endpoint.

```
HttpResponse response = future.get();
```

Is this line required ? As I don't need to capture response.

Comment: Have you considered that its maybe not the best idea to rely on that HTTP connection to stay alive for hours? Thats not what HTTP is designed to do.

Comment: I may not need HTTP Connection to be alive...I just need to trigger the endpoint and forget. Let the job happen async.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not needed. The line:

```
HttpResponse response = future.get();
```

blocks your thread until the there is a HTTP response or connection breaks. Check out [Future.get() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get())